# Where do I go to edit this area?

Tags: functions, customization, child-theme, theme-customizer, editor

[image: Edit]

I need to edit the area shown in my photo.  I am using a child theme. I am unable to ask the question to the theme's website as I don't have a proper subscription.  I have tried looking at both the theme customization and the `functions.php` and could not find this anywhere.  Any help from you guys would be great!

Comment: Look in header.php.

Comment: Theme normally will have a theme options page. Look for it. Probably under Appearance.

Comment: I have been told that it is under the framework/legacy/cranium/headers/views/{your stack}/global/_navbar.php area.  I do not know php so I do not know how to change it there.  Thank you all for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site :)

Since you already know that the item you want to change is in `framework/legacy/cranium/headers/views/global/_navbar.php` then the matter of changing it is very easy and straightforward.

**First:**

Create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) (if you haven't already). A child theme will allow you to change just the things you want while preserving the other features of the original theme.

**Next:**

Once you have your child theme, **copy** the `_navbar.php` file to your child theme directory: but make sure to **follow the folder organization of the parent theme**. So in this case, the copied `_navbar.php` file should be in a directory like this:

```
your-child-theme/framework/legacy/cranium/headers/views/global/_navbar.php
```

**And finally:**

Open the `_navbar.php` of your child theme in your preferred code editor, and change the text you need and save it. Your theme will load it in place of the original file in the parent theme.

Last notes: even though the file has a `.php` extension, you should still be able to read it and find what you need to change. I encourage you to try it :)

P.S. If you have any problems, let us know here. If you would like, you can even [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/333605/edit) your original question to add details to clarify it. For example, you can also post the code of `_navbar.php` if you need help with it.